# How to make a query for showing records where time is not more then 30 mins

Tags: android

I want to make query to get record within the past 30 mins.

```
                        String CREATE_FOJ_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOJ
            + "(" + KEY_FOJID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FOJPICKUPPOINT
            + " TEXT," + KEY_FOJDESTINATION + " TEXT," + KEY_FOJPICKUPTIME
             + KEY_FOJFARES + " TEXT," + 
                            KEY_FOJSPECIAL
            + " TEXT," +KEY_FOJVIA + 
                         " TEXT," + KEY_FOJMILAGE
            + " TEXT" + ")";



    ////////     this is my query //////////////

                    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FOJ +" ORDER BY "+ 
         KEY_FOJPICKUPTIME;
```

Comment: how to get time beofre 30 mins???????

Comment: what time format you have in which column?

Comment: im using text for date time   KEY_FOJPICKUPPOINT
    + " TEXT,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Works for MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE your_timestamp_columnname BETWEEN timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) AND timestamp(NOW())
```

Comment: what is Date-sub time interval etc please tell according to my tablle for sqllite

Comment: DATE_SUB() is a function that subtracts the known time interval from a date.

Comment: i get solution time and get time before 30 mins using this line of code  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTime(calendar.getTime());
  calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-30);
  java.util.Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
 now how i will makw query using this time?